# Is there any difference when creating numpy matrix in the following ways?

Tags: python, numpy

When I pratice numpy matrix these days, I create a matrix in this way:

```
theta = np.mat([1,1])
temp = np.mat(theta)
```

then I excute the following code for example

```
temp[0,0] = theta[0,0] - 0.3
print(temp, theta)
```

but the answer is so **unexpected**:

```
[[0 1]] [[0 1]]
```

but when I tried the another way:

```
theta = np.mat([1,1])
temp = np.mat(np.ones(a.shape))
```

the answer is totally **right**

Later I found that in fact, in the first way, temp is a view of theta, when change temp's value, theta will change too, but Can anyone explain the result I got?
why excute the following code will get `[[0 1]] [[0 1]]`

```
theta = np.mat([1,1])
temp = np.mat(theta)
temp[0,0] = theta[0,0] - 0.3
print(temp, theta)
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: From the data type of the numbers, numpy concludes that the dtype of the matrix should be an integer type. Specify dtype explicitly or change one number to 1.0

Comment: Stop looking at np.mat.  It's obsolete.

Comment: Someone else had the same problem a few days ago, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60479860/901925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start off with mentioning it's recommended to stop using the [matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) class, and it may be removed in future versions of numpy.

The reason for the difference is how the default values are initialized. For the way it's being initialized `theta = np.mat([1,1])`, it's defaulting to an **integer** type, and as such it's not handling the subtraction by a **float** in the way you're expecting, and is instead truncating your result.

When looking at the [numpy.ones](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) documention, it specifies this:

> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array, e.g., numpy.int8. **Default is numpy.float64.**

So you're getting a default value set of **floats** when doing `temp = np.mat(np.ones(a.shape))`,  which works with the type of float subtraction operation you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it is really helpful